# Ubuntu to Windows + php/mysql xml script not responive

Tags: php, mysql, windows, unix, mamp

I have written some code for google maps using php and mysql.  I have been forced to migrate from ubuntu to windows (to use dreamweaver).

On windows I have installed mamp, created the database, table and populated it.

In ubuntu when I run the php/xml/ajax script the query results are returned and everything is great.

In windows, when I run the same php/xml/ajax script, the query results in nothing.  NO errors about not connecting to the database (even if I change the database name to something non existant).  SO clearly something simple is wrong.  I placed all htm/php files in the htdoc directory (no subdirectories) within MAMP.  What might be the problem here???  I havent used MAMP before so its possible I am not putting the files in the correct directory (services are running according to mamp)

Comment: can you post Apache log?

Comment: nothing really sticking out in the apache log, but php_error shows [01-Mar-2016 04:21:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\MAMP\htdocs\phpsqlajax_genxml2.php:15
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\phpsqlajax_genxml2.php on line 15

[01-Mar-2016 04:22:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\MAMP\htdocs\phpsqlajax_genxml2.php:15
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\phpsqlajax_genxml2.php on line 15

Comment: line 15 $connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

It means that mysql extension is not loaded. Try change `mysql_connect()` to `mysqli_connect()`.

Your MAMP installation may be using mysqli extension. See `php.ini` file and look for line

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

If you still want to use mysql extension then change it to something like

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```